# How do I declare and call a function that asks for input in C++?

Tags: c++, function, printing, input, return

I would like to know how to declare and call this function from within the main:

```
void Part1()
{
int array1[10];
int n;
int i;
for (i=1; i<=10; i++) 
    {
    cout<<"Please enter an entry for position "<< i<<": "<<endl; 
    cin>>n;
    array1[i] = n;
    }
cout<<endl;
i = 0;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) 
    {
    cout<<array1[i]<<endl; 

    }
return 0;
}
```

When I try to run my int main() I get nothing. I am aware that void does not return anything, but I thought simply calling the function (ie "Part1") would work. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: This is how I have been calling it:

```
int main (){
Part1;

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show where you call it.

Comment: Also, array indices are 0-based so your first loop will go out of bounds of `array1`.

Comment: Out of bound memory access in the first for loop. Use the indexing just like in the second loop.

Comment: `int main() { Part1(); }`

Comment: your function can also not be of type void and return type int

Comment: You might benefit from purchasing and studying a good C++ introductory book. Stack Overflow has an excellent list to recommend: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @Tom I did not catch that, thanks.

Comment: you should be able to call `cin >> array1[i]` as well. in addition to that your second for loop can look like this: `for(;i < 10; ++i)`

Comment: How about reading a C++ tutorial before asking elementary questions?

Comment: No need to be so bitter, Carbonic Acid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call a function, you need to use parentheses: `Part1();`. The parentheses contain the arguments that will be passed to the function, but in your case there are none so the parentheses are empty.

Also, the index of your first `for` loop is incorrect. Your array's indices start at 0 and end at 9. You seemed to get this correct in the second `for` loop but not in the first. It should be `for (int i=0; i<10; i++)`.

Answer (score 3):

In order to invoke a function, you must use the function-call operator, namely, `()`.

Like this:

```
int main (){
  Part1();

  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```